how can I remove salt from water chemically(a direct reaction) ,or convert it to other compound in order to irrigate the soil or any substitutions?
we've a salty water that is approximately 20%  wt./wt. conc.(a soaking solution) in a food product  company we consumes daily a huge amount of water about 3000L  of water , we are seeking about a way to treat with this amount  after  completing  the soaking such as irrigation  but we need a low cost way to convert this amount to be suitable for irrigation

I don't see any connection to "nucleophilic substitution". Please clarify.

There are many, widely used, desalination technologies (use to create drinkable water from sea water for example). None use chemical reactions to achieve this. If any exist they are not remotely economical.

Also, desalination of 20% salt solution would be expensive. The most salty seas have about 4%.

Its not necessary  to purify water  my idea  is to react it or convert it to other  compound by reacting with other salt so  it couldn't be  bad for  irrigation or   good for the soil  as a  chemical fertilizer

It is not possible to remove salt chemically from salty water.
What you can do is remove water from salty water by evaporation, using solar energy. This technique is used in hot countries like North Africa to produce drinkable water from sea water. All you have to do is dig a long canal like an irrigation canal, in the sand of the beach. Now cover the channel by a long roof made of two rather long and narrow glass plates touching one another and glued on top of the roof, and hanging on both sides of the channel. Water gets slowly evaporated in this covered canal by the sun light crossing the glass roof. Then water vapor gets condensed on and under the glass plates. After a while condensed water runs down the glass plate, and falls into a rain gutter installed on the level of the soil, provided the lower part of the glass plates are in the gutter, parallel to the canal. Pure water is recovered from this gutter.

For less-salty brines, revers osmosis might be practical. As it is, you're in a bit of a pickle.

All I can suggest is to distil the saltwater repeatedly until the salt concentration is appropriate for irrigation.
